# Interface Builder crashes (iOSRenderServer)

Tags: ios, xcode, appcode

On closing my storyboard with Xcode (by quitting Xcode itself or switching to another file), it makes me awaiting for a while until I do Force Quit.

On opening my storyboard with AppCode, I see the alert about iOSRenderServer just crashed. Well it's the only project with this trouble, and I believe there is some mistakes inside storyboard, but I can't figure out what exactly is wrong.

Somebody have seen this before?

**reason: 'MainScreenScale is not valid: 0.000000'**

```
Process:               iOSRenderServer [25123]
Path:                  /Applications/AppCode.app/Contents/plugins/appcode-designer/iOSRenderServer.app/iOSRenderServer
Identifier:            iOSRenderServer
Version:               1.0 (1.0)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        appcode [25007]
Responsible:           appcode [25007]
User ID:               503

Date/Time:             2015-04-12 10:40:12.951 +0300
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.3 (14D131)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        82A2E61F-7F5F-9CDC-F8CC-3AE376F99B61

Sleep/Wake UUID:       38298837-20D2-4686-8D6D-EEC965606B5D

Time Awake Since Boot: 54000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       2400 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'MainScreenScale is not valid: 0.000000'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d683c65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010d31cbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d683aca +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
3   Foundation                          0x000000010cf31a57 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:] + 169
4   BaseBoard                           0x000000010f1c89c1 ___BSMainScreenGetInfo_block_invoke + 351
5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010dc91964 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010dc7f902 dispatch_once_f + 129
7   BaseBoard                           0x000000010f1c8808 BSMainScreenScale + 43
8   FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010f156b0e -[FBSDisplay initWithCADisplay:isMainDisplay:seed:tags:scale:] + 234
9   UIKit                               0x000000010bba7d02 -[UIApplication __completeAndRunAsPlugin] + 355
10  iOSRenderServer                     0x000000010b8b0a61 -[AppDelegate doStart] + 129
11  iOSRenderServer                     0x000000010b8b3b84 my_registerAsSystemApp + 132
12  UIKit                               0x000000010bba7ad3 -[UIApplication _run] + 302
13  UIKit                               0x000000010bbaa900 UIApplicationMain + 1282
14  iOSRenderServer                     0x000000010b8b3fa2 main + 962
15  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010dcc1145 start + 1

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000010dfc9286 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_sim_c.dylib           0x000000010dd6919a abort + 129
2   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000010db3b481 abort_message + 257
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000010db633d5 default_terminate_handler() + 267
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000010d31ce19 _objc_terminate() + 103
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000010db60b01 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000010db60b73 std::terminate() + 51
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000010d31cd93 objc_terminate + 9
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000010dc91978 _dispatch_client_callout + 28
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000010dc7f902 dispatch_once_f + 129
10  com.apple.BaseBoard             0x000000010f1c8808 BSMainScreenScale + 43
11  com.apple.FrontBoardServices    0x000000010f156b0e -[FBSDisplay initWithCADisplay:isMainDisplay:seed:tags:scale:] + 234
12  com.apple.UIKit                 0x000000010bba7d02 -[UIApplication __completeAndRunAsPlugin] + 355
13  com.jetbrains.iOSRenderServer   0x000000010b8b0a61 -[AppDelegate doStart] + 129
14  com.jetbrains.iOSRenderServer   0x000000010b8b3b84 my_registerAsSystemApp + 132
15  com.apple.UIKit                 0x000000010bba7ad3 -[UIApplication _run] + 302
16  com.apple.UIKit                 0x000000010bbaa900 UIApplicationMain + 1282
17  com.jetbrains.iOSRenderServer   0x000000010b8b3fa2 main + 962
18  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000010dcc1145 start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000010dfca232 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000010dc81d94 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000010dfc994a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010dff840d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000010dfc994a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010dff840d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000010dfc994a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010dff840d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000006  rcx: 0x00007fff54355e78  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x000000000000070b  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007fff54355ea0  rsp: 0x00007fff54355e78
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x000000010dd8f600  r10: 0x0000000008000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x00007fff54356000  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x000000010e001300  r15: 0x00007fff54355ee0
  rip: 0x000000010dfc9286  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x000000010db643b2
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the following

1. [NSLayoutContraint constraintWithItem ...] method are nil.
2. You could have switched off auto layout , but adding a constraint to subview via a code. 
   3.The view hasn't been created in the nib/UIView, but the constraint has been applied, move the Constraint code from the initWithNib method to viewDidLoad.

Comment: Thanks, will check.
But I think I don't setup it in code.

And how MainScreenScale could be affected by Auto Layout?

Answer (score 0):

The storyboard file is a simple text file in XML format. So, if Xcode won't open it, just use a text editor of your choice. Then search the file for MainScreenScale and see if there is something strange.

If you can remember the last edits you made on your storyboard, try to roll them back.

And take care on not to mess up the XML structure. Make a copy of the file first.

Best solution: If you have your project under Source Control, roll back to the last commit.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out.

After doing something like git-bisect (remove some VCs and its contents until IB stops crashing), the reason was found.

I have my own view as titleView on two screens. I don't know exactly why, but this had been causing my troubles. Moving my own titleView from IB to code stopped these crashes at all.

And for now, it would be great to understand why exactly this happened.
Maybe there is anything wrong implemented inside my view...

Comment: But there were no problems for few weeks about this titleView